# Swapping two strings in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

What does the arguments (char * &str1, char * &str2) specify in the swap function? What if they are replaced by (char &str1, char &str2) and char *temp=str1 with char &temp=str1 inside the swap function?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap(char * &str1, char * &str2)
{
char *temp = str1;
str1 = str2;
str2 = temp;
}

int main()
{
char *str1 = "GEEKS";
char *str2 = "FOR GEEKS";
swap(str1, str2);
cout<<"str1 is "<<str1<<endl;
cout<<"str2 is "<<str2<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you think this function does, what you think it should do if it was char&

Comment: Danger here: `char *str1 = "GEEKS";` `"GEEKS"` is a `const char *` not a `char *` You should have a compiler warning advising that you not do this. Undefined behaviour will result if you modify what is at the pointer as opposed to merely swapping the pointers.

Comment: Replacing to char& produced the same output. Why it is necessary to declare the type as pointer to the reference (char * &str1) @UKMonkey

Comment: "pointer to the reference" - nope, other way around - reference to a pointer.

Comment: When you pass a pointer into a function, you can modify the data at the pointer, and since the caller and the function are both looking at the same location both will see changes. However, the pointer passed into the function is merely copied. If you change where the copy is pointing, the caller won't know. The caller has the original, and the original is unchanged.  Using a a reference to the pointer means both the caller and the function are using the same pointer, very similar to the pointer in the first place. Read up on pass by reference and pass by value.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks for the explanation, got it cleared :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does the arguments (char * &str1, char * &str2) specify in the swap function?

they specify that parameters are of type reference to pointer to char. This means that function might change the value of the variable that was provided as argument to this function.

> What if they are replaced by (char &str1, char &str2) and char *temp=str1 with char &temp=str1 inside the swap function?

then you will get compiler error, because you will still call it like: `swap(str1, str2);`, you would have to change the call to `swap(*str1, *str2);` and then you will swap first letter of both strings.

[edit]

Your code includes also another subtle error, you use `using namespace std;` which causes `std::swap` to be called when you change your `swap` function signature to `void swap(char &str1, char &)`.

You should also see warnigs like:

> main.cpp:17:14: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wpedantic]
>    char *str1 = "GEEKS";

this is because string literals are const pointers, otherwise you introduce UB in your code. You should change to `const char *str1`

Comment: I dont get any compiler error, instead I get the same output with the strings perfectly swapped. @Marcinj

Comment: @SrinathThumati Are you sure the code built and you are not running the executable that was created last time the program built? If you can confirm that you did indeed build that code, please let us know what compiler you used and what error and warning levels you set. Trying to stuff `char *` into `char` should have the compiler screaming and refusing to build.

Comment: @SrinathThumati that is because you are calling then std::swap which is template, that is also why you should never use `using namespace std;`

Comment: @user4581301, I compiled the code with online IDE's, Geeksforgeeks IDE and ideone IDE. You say this execution happened because of the error or warning levels set up in these online compilers?

Comment: @Marcinj You are right. I thought the effect of namespace std would have only if i use them with the keyword std:: thanks for response :)

Comment: @SrinathThumati I was wrong. Marcin spotted what I did not.

Answer (score 0):

> What does the arguments (char * &str1, char * &str2) specify in the swap function?

They specify that this function accepts 2 references to pointers to `char`. If in doubt use `typedef` (at least in your head):

```
typedef char * pchar;
void swap( pchar &str1, pchar &str2 );
```

> What if they are replaced by (char &str1, char &str2) and char *temp=str1 with char &temp=str1 inside the swap function?

Then you will swap two `char`s instead of two pointers to `char`